# Is there an equivalent in tcl to a dataframe in R (or Python or Julia)?

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to perform some data operations in some Tcl macros.  I'm experienced using R dataframes to perform many of these operations, but I can't seem to find something equivalent in Tcl.

The only thing I can find is to use a Matrix or possibly using an inMemory  SQLite DB.

Is there any better or standard solutions that can be used intrinsically in Tcl directly?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do (which "data operations")?

Comment: I want to perform some basic data operations such as joining two tables, performing some simple pivots or basic filter subsets the dataframe based on values in one of the columns

Comment: How big is your data (expected number of rows and columns)?

Comment: @R Yoda Varies quite a bit.  Some are small around 10,000 rows, and some are large (up to 100 million rows) and maybe 20-30 columns of mixed type (integers, doubles, strings, datetimes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know exactly what operations R dataframes provide, but [TclRAL](http://repos.modelrealization.com/cgi-bin/fossil/tclral) provides a complete relational algebra that allows you to define relations (aka tables) and perform the usual relational algebra operations, e.g. project, select, join, etc. It is a "C" based extension which integrates relation values into the underlying Tcl value system. You can think of it as an in-memory relational system with functionality similar to what you can obtain with a SQL database but using Tcl commands instead of a query language.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into this.  Is this fundamentally similar to creating an SQLite in memory db?  How is the performance of TclRal generally?

Comment: In the spirit of full disclosure, I am the author of TclRAL and it is fundamental to many programs that I write. TclRAL distinguishes between relation values which may be treated as Tcl values and relation variables which are more like SQL tables. Commands are provided to manipulate both concepts and the man page docs give the detailed commands and arguments. As for performance, I've not had any problems. It is a C based extension, so it is about the best I can do in that area.

Comment: yes, I noticed the paper was authored by someone with a very similar name to yours.   I appreciate getting advice directly from the source.